# Use cursor in LOOP in new QUERY

Tags: plsql

"I missing the forest through the trees..."

I want to query each column of a table which I retrieve in a FOR LOOP, but the inner query doesn't return the right thing.
Seems that the inner query not use the current column_name.

```
DECLARE
v_max_TS TIMESTAMP;

BEGIN

FOR cols IN (SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_cols WHERE table_name = '<tablename>')
LOOP
    SELECT 
    MAX(CURR_TIMESTAMP) INTO v_max_TS
    FROM <tablename> 
    WHERE cols.column_name IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY TO_TIMESTAMP(CURR_TIMESTAMP,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') DESC;

    dbms_output.put_line(cols.column_name || '         ' || v_max_TS); 
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? You're fetching all the columns for a table and then finding the max value of the `curr_timestamp` column every time. This makes no sense? Also, is the `curr_timestamp` column guaranteed to be in all the tables you're likely to query against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the fact that your query doesn't make much sense (as Boneist wrote as a comment), that won't work as you need to use dynamic SQL (`execute immediate`) for such a purpose.

Here's an example based on Scott's schema. Have a look, adjust it if necessary.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(200);  -- will hold the SELECT statement
  3    v_max varchar2(30);
  4  begin
  5    for cols in (select column_name
  6                 from all_tab_cols
  7                 where table_name = 'DEPT'
  8                )
  9    loop
 10      l_str := 'select max(' || cols.column_name ||') from dept';
 11      execute immediate l_str into v_max;
 12      dbms_output.put_line(cols.column_name ||': '|| v_max);
 13    end loop;
 14  end;
 15  /
DEPTNO: 40
DNAME: SALES
LOC: NEW YORK

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you, dynamic sql was the key!